OpenAPI generates AdditionalProperties field twice
I am generating Swagger client via the OpenAPI but getting an error for additionalProperties as it was defined twice.
The json schema was generated from FastEndpoints project, I tried to add schema filter configuration to disallow the AdditionalPropertiesAllowed - yet no luck.
I'm trying to understand how do we configure the additionalProperties to appear only once in the json schema:

UPDATE:
The issue that I encountered on the generated json schema with additionalProperties defined twice is when I try to generate a CSharpClient through json the client throws an error with
additionalProperties defined twice in the model.

You could try experimenting with DocumentSettings like below:
builder.Services
   .AddFastEndpoints()
   .SwaggerDocument(c => c.DocumentSettings = docSettings =>
   {
       docSettings.PostProcess = doc =>
       {
           foreach (var definition in doc.Definitions)
           {
               definition.Value.AdditionalPropertiesSchema = null;
               // and/or 
               definition.Value.AllowAdditionalProperties = false;
           }
       };
   });

It caused additionalProperties to disappear. So maybe it's worth taking a look.
Original answer
This is because in new C# projects, there are nullable reference types (NRTs) turned on by default. Go to your .csproj file and see that you will have set:
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>

And this will cause Swagger to generate these properties.
If you would disable NRTs, like below:
<Nullable>disable</Nullable>

Then Swagger would generate just "additionalProperties": false.
And the reason there are multiple "additionalProperties" properties, is that this is just applicable for every object, and so Swagger generates this information for each object. Not once.

Thanks for the explanation! I tried the above snippet however the generated CSharpClient still generates additionalProperties with jsonextensiondata attributes.
After experimenting, this works
definition.Value.AllowAdditionalProperties = false;

On my earlier attempts, I am setting this AllowAdditionalProperties under the SchemaFilter config which doesn't work either.

@RuzelR. Glad to hear that you could figure it out. If my answer was any helpful, you should consider accepting/upvoting

tried to replicate your problem with the following code:
var bld = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
bld.Services
   .AddFastEndpoints()
   .SwaggerDocument();

var app = bld.Build();
app.UseFastEndpoints()
   .UseSwaggerGen();
app.Run();

sealed class MyRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

sealed class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

sealed class MyEndpoint : Endpoint<MyRequest>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Post("test");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(MyRequest r, CancellationToken c)
    {
        await SendAsync(r);
    }
}

but i can't seem to, because it generates the correct swagger json as follows:
{
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "MyRequest": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "nullable": true,
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Item"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Item": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

please update your question with how exactly to produce the problem.
